# Why does this code do work: "map.apply(1)+=3"

Tags: scala, scala-collections

```
val map = scala.collection.mutable.Map(1 -> 2)

map(1) += 3
map.apply(1) += 3
(map.apply(1)).+=(3)
```

I don't understand why the codes are all compiling fine.

In the first case, I think the code is expanded to `map(1) = map(1) + 3`, and to `map.update(1, map(1) + 3)`.
But in the second and third cases, 
`map.apply(1) = map.apply(1) + 3` causes a compilation error, of cause.

How are the second and third code expanded to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `:replay -Xprint:typer` from the scala console:

1) `map(1) += 3` expands to:

```
map.update(1, map.apply(1).+(3))
```

2) `map.apply(1) += 3` expands to:

```
map.update(1, map.apply(1).+(3))
```

3) `(map.apply(1)).+=(3)` expands to:

```
map.update(1, map.apply(1).+(3))
```

---

**EDIT Answer to the question in the comments**

> If all three expansions are the same, why second and third causes a compilation error?

The second and third: `map.apply(1) += 3` and `(map.apply(1)).+=(3)` are compiling fine and are also equivalent.

What I tried to prove with my answer is that: `map.apply(1) += 3` doesn't expand to `map.apply(1) = map.apply(1) + 3` <del>as explained by @som-snytt in the first part of his answer.</del>

BTW `map(1) = map(1) + 3` **does not** expands to `map.update(1, map(1) + 3)` as stated in the question.

I hope this clarify my answer.

Comment: I am a bit confused. If all three expansions are the same, why second and third causes a compilation error - at least this is written in the question?

Comment: Thanks for answering! I didn't know the option `-Xprint:typer`. It seems useful :D

Comment: But this is incorrect. What you say doesn't expand that way, does expand that way. I don't say what you say I say. I say that, anomalously, the compiler doesn't correctly convert the explicit `map.apply` to `map.update`. I'll expand my answer in case I am as correct as I think I am.

Answer (score 2):

The rule for update is [in the spec under assignments](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#assignments), and expansion of [assignment operators here](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#assignment-operators).

The question is why is explicit `m.apply` not taken as `m()` for purposes of the update rule.

The two forms are supposed to be [equivalent](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#function-applications).

Someone just [debated](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-debate/KPynCUvvirI/6UpYEFQ8CAAJ) update syntax with [examples](https://gist.github.com/acdenhartog/a47fad6ebe8d32ff0ff5).

```
scala> import reflect.runtime.universe._
import reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> val map = scala.collection.mutable.Map(1 -> 2)
map: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2)

scala> reify(map(1) += 3)
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.Expr[Unit] = Expr[Unit]($read.map.update(1, $read.map.apply(1).$plus(3)))

scala> reify(map.apply(1) += 3)
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.Expr[Unit] = Expr[Unit]($read.map.update(1, $read.map.apply(1).$plus(3)))

scala> reify(map(1) = map(1) + 3)
res2: reflect.runtime.universe.Expr[Unit] = Expr[Unit]($read.map.update(1, $read.map.apply(1).$plus(3)))

scala> reify(map.apply(1) = map.apply(1) + 3)
<console>:16: error: missing argument list for method apply in trait MapLike
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `apply _` or `apply(_)` instead of `apply`.
       reify(map.apply(1) = map.apply(1) + 3)
                 ^

scala> map.apply.update(1, map.apply(1) + 3)
<console>:16: error: missing argument list for method apply in trait MapLike
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `apply _` or `apply(_)` instead of `apply`.
       map.apply.update(1, map.apply(1) + 3)
           ^
```

Edit: FWIW, [that's just how it is](https://gitter.im/scala/contributors?at=569c8a03c391361d48ebb10d).

Edit:

This is the anomaly:

```
scala> val m = collection.mutable.Map(1->2)
m: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2)

scala> m(1) = m(1) + 3

scala> m(1) += 3

scala> m.apply(1) += 3

scala> m.apply(1) = m.apply(1) + 3
<console>:13: error: missing argument list for method apply in trait MapLike
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `apply _` or `apply(_)` instead of `apply`.
       m.apply(1) = m.apply(1) + 3
         ^
```

Since these expressions are all equivalent, they should all compile to an invocation of `update`.

The last expression fails to typecheck because the compiler does a mechanical rewrite to `m.apply.update(1, m.apply(1) + 3)` instead of `m.update`.

The explanation in gitter chat is that, well, the compiler isn't required to be smart enough to recognize `m.apply(1)` as `m(1)` in this context. After all, possibly ambiguities ensue. What if `apply` is parameterless and returns a value with an `update` method? Do you take `m.apply(1)` as `m(1)` only if it doesn't typecheck otherwise?

It's clear that, by the spec, `m(1) += ???` is expanded to `m(1) = m(1) + ???` and then converted to `m.update(1, m(1) + ???)`.

In the code, the two transformations (converting `op=` to `x = x op expr` and `x(1) = ???` to `x.update(1, ???)`) are compressed:

[Deciding if something is mutable](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/TreeInfo.scala#L285)

[On error with op=, attempt conversion to assignment](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Typers.scala#L4518)

[Converting to update](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Typers.scala#L4629) (or to plain assignment).

It might be possible to work around the limitation in the implementation, but it's not obvious that it would spec nicely (as above, where `apply` might be paramless).

Then should `m.apply(1) += 3` fail to compile, for symmetry? If the compiler worked harder to retain the source expression, it could at least be more consistent in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this works in 2.12.0-M3

```
C:\Users\erichardson>scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.0-M3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_66).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala>  val map = scala.collection.mutable.Map(1 -> 2)
map: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2)

scala>  map(1) += 3

scala> map
res1: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 5)

scala> map.apply(1) += 3

scala> map
res3: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 8)

scala> (map.apply(1)).+=(3)

scala> map
res5: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 11)

scala>
```